# Boton a la derecha en Select2 - Solucion

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4, select2

Mas que solicitar ayuda, quiero dejar una solucion (no se si sera la mas correcta) sobre agregar un boton a la derecha de un select, pero el cual queda desalineado y posiblemente le ha sucedido a muchos:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Investigando para mi caso no he encontrado solucion que me ayude, pero revisando los estilos css pude encontrar un metodo que funcione, pero solo para mi caso (este selector), ya que en los demas no necesito hacer este cambio:

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="Producto">
            Producto <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="input-group" style="flex-wrap: inherit;">
                <select
                    id="Producto"
                    name="Producto"
                    class="form-control select2"
                    data-placeholder="Seleccione una producto..."
                    data-allow-clear="true"
                    required
                >
                </select>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En resumen es envolver, como indica bootstrap, en un div con clase `input-group` el select y el boton y a este incluir el estilo `style="flex-wrap: inherit;"`, y se corrigio de inmediato:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Espero les sirva.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrFHQ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp1oC.png

Comment: El formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Redáctalo como pregunta autorrespondida.